# Putting the dir_id using boxr package in R

Tags: r, box

I am trying to setup the working directory-using the url-"https:\..."

Code:

```
box_setwd(url)

Error:-
Error in box_id(dir_id) :
box.com API ids must be (coercible to) 64-bit integers.
```

I am exploring bit64 package meanwhile it will be great to have a workaround.
I hope the details are enough.

Comment: I could solve the problem from the box_ls() documentation- let me know the next step

Answer (score 0):

the dir and other ids pertaining to the boxr commands are the numeric extensions in  the url- it's available in the [documentation](https://github.com/brendan-r/boxr)